# Locating the element and getText() value

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The following is the HTML code,

```
<span>
<b>Order number:</b>
</span>
<span>A36HASJH</span>
```

The span value AA36HASJH is a dynamic element which changes in each ordering session. How can I locate the above element and store the value in one string.

When I tried using xpath:

```
String orderNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='topBanner']/div[5]/div/span[2]")).getText();
System.out.println(orderNumber);
```

It prints the xpath and not the orderNumber. Please let me know how to write a proper xpath and get the value of the orderNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below xpath:

```
//b[text()='Order number:']/following::span
```

Code:

```
String orderNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='Order number:']/following::span")).getText();
System.out.println(orderNumber);
```